# Length of continuously differentiable curve (Theorem 6.27 Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

So I know the length of a curve as defined in Rudin's *Principals of Mathematical Analysis* is defined as $\Lambda(\gamma) = \sup\Lambda(P, \gamma),$ taking the supremum over all partitions of $[a,b]$. Then the theorem says if the curve is continuous then $\Lambda(\gamma) = \int_a^b \lvert \gamma'(t) \rvert \, dt$.

I want to know if the following is true:  given a curve $\gamma$ that is continuously differentiable on $[a, b)$ is $\Lambda(\gamma) = 
\lim_{d\to b} \int_a^d \lvert \gamma'(t) \rvert \, dt$, where we consider the refinement having one more point $d$.

Comment: You need some conditions on $\gamma$ such as AC. I have no idea what you mean by refinement

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, but what is AC? We say a partition P' is a refinement of P if every point of P is a point of P', or $P\subset P'$

Comment: Absolutely continuous, so that $\gamma'$ exists at suitably many points. I know what a partition is, but have no idea what that has to do with what you have written above...

Comment: @copper.hat you're right, edited my question to continuously differentiable curve

Comment: If the curve is defined on $[a,b)$ then what does the $d$ mean in $\int_a^d$??? I really have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @copper.hat d is just a point in the partition, but I made a mistake its limit as $d\to b$ so trying to apply the theorem

Comment: Well, if $\gamma$ is $C^1$ then it is bounded and it is easy to see that $\int_d^b |\gamma'(t)|dt \to 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you please explain more? Also don't understand why you are integrating from d to b and not a to d

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gamma'$ is continuous, it is bounded by some constant $B$.

Then $\int_d^b |\gamma'(t)| dt \le B (b-d)$, and hence $\lim_{d \uparrow b} \int_d^b |\gamma'(t)| dt = 0$. Since $\Lambda(\gamma) = \int_a^d |\gamma'(t)| dt + \int_d^b |\gamma'(t)| dt$, we see that
$\lim_{d \uparrow b} \int_a^d |\gamma'(t)| dt = \Lambda(\gamma)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the curve is only continuous on [a,b) half open interval..so it may not be bounded

Comment: Then the curve need not have finite length?

Comment: Let $\gamma(t) = (t, \sin { 1\over 1-t})$ on $[0,1)$. This is smooth but has infinite length.